# Add-in framework: get AddIn location

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, maf

In .NET Add-in framework, can I get AddIn dll location at host side?

AddInToken contains _addin field that has dll location, but I cannot get it because it's private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing public on the token you can use.  You could implement your own method in the AddInAdapter that gets the assembly from the interface implementation.

So you would have to activate the token and then call a method on the activated object to determine the assembly location.

For example, if you captured your interface in an object called _view, you could do:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(_view.GetType()).Location
```